# How to keep track of actions called by a jQuery dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

I have a bit of a dillema :)

I have a link for users to vote on an item.  A click on a link generated a jQuery AJAX call checking if the person is logged in.  If not, the dialog box displays a form to login.

But the problem is that the jQuery call to log in and the whole bit with the popup box is in a different place.

What I need to do is check if user got logged in successfully, and update the vote count.

I am doing it on this site: http://www.problemio.com

Here is my jQuery code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
     var $dialog = $('#loginpopup')
       .dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         title: 'Login Dialog'
       }); 

        $("#newprofile").click(function () {
          $("#login_div").hide();
          $("#newprofileform").show();
        });


    $('.vote_up').click(function() 
    {        
        problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&vote=+';

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/vote.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data)
                {           
                    // ? :)
                    alert (data);   
                },
                error : function(data) 
                {
                    errorMessage = data.responseText;

                    if ( errorMessage == "not_logged_in" )
                    {
                        // Try to create the popup that asks user to log in.
                        $dialog.dialog('open');

                        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert ("not");
                    }

                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });


        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });

    $('.vote_down').click(function() 
    {
        alert("down");

        problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&vote=-';        

        //Return false to prevent page navigation
        return false;
    });    
});
</script>
```

It all works except right after the line `$dialog.dialog('open');` - I don't know how to

1. Get a signal back for success of fail, and don't know exactly how to
2. Update the very item that was voted on since it is just one of many items that can be voted on in the page.

How can I do these two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

1. Have a hidden input within the `div` that is your login dialog.
2. Set that with the `problem_id` before you do the `.dialog('open')`
3. On the success callback of the `Login` button click, retrieve `problem_id` from the hidden input and perform vote-up or vote-down.

Hope that helps

EDIT: (Trying to code a workable example after OP's second comment)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $dialog = $('#loginpopup')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'Login Dialog'
                });

        var $problemId = $('#theProblemId', '#loginpopup');

        $("#newprofile").click(function () {
            $("#login_div").hide();
            $("#newprofileform").show();
        });


        $('.vote_up').click(function() {
            var problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");
            voteUp(problem_id);
            //Return false to prevent page navigation
            return false;
        });

        var voteUp = function(problem_id) {
            var dataString = 'problem_id=' + problem_id + '&vote=+';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/vote.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                    // ? :)
                    alert(data);
                },
                error : function(data) {
                    errorMessage = data.responseText;
                    if (errorMessage == "not_logged_in") {
                        //set the current problem id to the one within the dialog
                        $problemId.val(problem_id);

                        // Try to create the popup that asks user to log in.
                        $dialog.dialog('open');

                        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("not");
                    }

                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
        };

        $('.vote_down').click(function() {
            alert("down");

            problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");

            var dataString = 'problem_id=' + problem_id + '&vote=-';

            //Return false to prevent page navigation
            return false;
        });

        $('#loginButton', '#loginpopup').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'url to do the login',
                success:function() {
                    //now call cote up 
                    voteUp($problemId.val());
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think there is an inherint problem with this approach in that I can not set the hidden field with that problem_id until the user clicks on that particular problem.  There are many problems on the page, and the system wouldn't know which problem_id to use until one is clicked.  Does that make sense? Is there still a way to make this work considering this limitation?

Comment: Witha little refactoring, it should be doable is what I still think, even with the constraint you mentioned. I have tried to enhance the code sample you provided by adding in the solution I suggested into it. See if that would help...